# How to Record both screen and video at same time in react?

Tags: reactjs, video, recording

i want to record screen using react-media-recorder along with camera video to be recorderd and then it become one video in order to play.

I recorded but i used two video elements to display play them.but i want to combine them. like all screen recording and there is a square box for user cam recorderd video.i used one video element on top of other.

Answer (score 0):

To combine videos, you need to perform video processing. Video processing involves a series of steps to process video data and create a new combined video material.

For example, you can use https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/

But I don't recommend performing video processing on the frontend because it requires significant computational power and can be much slower than on the backend. However, this decision depends on your goals and target audience.